# Unable use "parse_file" function from Syn, How to enable "parsing" attribute in Rust

Tags: rust, attributes, syn

I am trying to use `syn::parse_file` function from `syn` crate.

But, I unable to use it and found a function in the crate with `feature` attribute:

```rust
#[cfg(all(feature = "parsing", feature = "full"))] 
#[cfg_attr(doc_cfg, doc(cfg(all(feature = "parsing", feature = "full"))))]
pub fn parse_file(mut content: &str) -> Result<File> {
    // other code
}
```

<sup>Unable to find any discription of this feature.</sup>
How do I enable these features in my project?
And use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable a certain crate feature in the `Cargo.toml` file - where you specify the crate itself and its version.

For the [syn](https://crates.io/crates/syn) crate, the `parsing` feature is enabled by default but `full` is not, as described in the docs.

[Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) you can read more about how to enable features for your crates (dependencies).

Comment: Cargo.toml is not a config file, it's a package manifest. In general, it's all configs, but to avoid misunderstandings, you should use this term.